# doctrine query with parameters having multiple values

Tags: doctrine-query

I want to make a doctrine query in which each parameters can have multiple values (coming from a select multiple).

I have a table with a 'type' parameter that can have value of 1, 2, 3 or 4 and an 'online' parameter that can be 0 or 1.

My query so far is the following :

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('properties');

if (array_key_exists('type', $searchValues)) {

    $types = $searchValues['type'];
    $iterator = 0;

    foreach ($types as $type) {

        if ($iterator == 0) {

            $query->andWhere('properties.idPropertyType = ' . $type);

        } else {

            $query->orWhere('properties.onlineProperties = ' . $type);

        }

            $iterator++;

        }
    }

if (array_key_exists('status', $searchValues)) {

    $status = $searchValues['status'];
    $iterator = 0;

    foreach ($status as $statu) {

        if ($iterator == 0) {

            $query->andwhere('properties.onlineProperties = ' . $statu);

        } else {

            $query->andWhere('properties.onlineProperties = ' . $statu);

        }

        $iterator++;

    }

}

$properties = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

In the case of a search with parameter type = 1 and online = 0 and 1, I have results where type is another value than 1. I understand the reason why but I cannot figure out a proper way to make my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to build your query by hand manually, just use the (in) function from the QueryBuilder class. Try this:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('properties');

if(array_key_exists('type', $searchValues)){
    $types = $searchValues['type'];
    $query->andWhere($query->expr()->in('properties.idPropertyType', $types));
}

if(array_key_exists('status', $searchValues)){
    $status = $searchValues['status'];
    $query->andwhere($query->expr()->in('properties.onlineProperties', $status));
}

$properties = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am trying to figure out the error that I get :
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 145: Error: Expected Literal, got ')'

Comment: Based on what code? Can you post the code, is throwing you that error, please?

Comment: Excellent, this exactly what I needed! I fixed the problem checking if the array of the parameter is empty before end. However, I now face a new problem. i have another attribute which can have values of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and >5. But I will create a new question ;) Thanks !

Comment: Everything works like a charm for the attributes of the properties entity, however I cannot reach the attributes of the related entites 'constraints' and 'pricingInfo'. Impossible for me to do something like :
        $query->andwhere($query->expr()->in('properties.constraints.capacity', $capacity));
Any idea to make this work?

Comment: You have to add an INNER JOIN with the "constraints" entity to be able to access the attributes of that entity and then you can do the same as I showed you above in the code.

Comment: That's what I was trying but I still cannot get it to work. Below two versions of codes I tried:
1-

                $query->innerJoin('properties.constraints', 'constraints', Join::WITH, $query->expr()->in('properties.constraints', $capacity))

2- $query->innerJoin('properties.constraints', 'constraints', Join::WITH,
                    $query->expr()->eq('properties.idProperties', 'constraints.idProperties')
                );
                $query->andWhere($query->expr()->in('properties.constraints', $capacity));

Comment: I keep having : A single-valued association path expression to an inverse side is not supported in DQL queries. Instead of "properties.constraints" use an explicit join.

Comment: Try something like this: `code` $query->join('properties.constraints', 'constraints'); $query->expr()->in('constraints.capacity', $capacity)) `code` First you are doing a join with the constraint entity and then you are accessing to its capacity value to filter it out. @frogtube

Comment: Thanks @user3267053, I have it all working ! It took me quite some time but I figured it out yesterday.  My code :
$query->innerJoin('properties.constraints', 'constraints', Expr\Join::WITH,

                        $query->expr()->in('constraints.maxGuestsConstraints', $capacities)

                    );

Comment: I see what you did, in the same inner join condition you added the condition for the capacities, I'm glad you figure it out.